# Android Video and image Concat

Tags: java, android, video-capture

I have a problem, I am developing a video recording application in Android, at the end of the recording I want to include my logo image as last frame in the video, I would like to know how to do this is in Android Java, is there any sample code available for this

Comment: Nice, you can set the last frame of your Video as image. I haven't done thing but idea would be same.

Comment: Yes but how to do it in java ? thats the point I don't know